# Joining groups in a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a `List<Person>` where `Person` contains several data including a `GroupID` and a `PersonID`. This list can contain several thousand records of semi-sensitive data (Not very sensitive, but I still need to make the recipient of the list not be able to identify single individuals). I need to take all Groups who contain less than 4 Persons, and join them together under a new `GroupID` and then return a new List.

I have tried several linq-queries to get this to work but I'm really just stuck. I'm guessing I need to do some kind of GroupBy but I can't figure out where to group and how to return the data. (It still needs to be a `List<Person>`)

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: _"It still needs to be a List<Person>"_ But how can it be a `List<Person>` if the goal is to group the small groups together? A list of person contains no groups. I really don't understand this question. It's also not clear how it's related that the data is sensitive. Code says more than thousand words.

Comment: I may have been unclear. The List is of Person, but each Person has a GroupID. And where the number of Persons with a distinct GroupID I need to change the GroupID to a "fake" one. (The same fake one for all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
int newGroupID = 9; //random number, use your own logic obviously
var grouped = list.GroupBy(a => a.GroupID);
List<Person> newGroupList = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() < 4).SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
newGroupList.ForEach(p => p.GroupID = newGroupID);
//Now the original "list" will reflect the updated data
```

First line is just the new group number, obviously you should choose it according to a "free" int.
Then grouping by the GroupID, and choosing all the `Person` objects that belong to a group with fewer than 4 persons in it.

Lastly, we iterate over those persons and assign them the new GroupID. 
Since `Person` is a class and hence a reference type, you'll have the updated data in the original list.

Working example in [Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zHzmhF).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try even if the question is hard to understand. Are you looking for a way to group a `List<Person>` to a `IEnumerable<List<Person>>` where the resulting sequence contains all groups as list apart from the small-group which is in a single list? Then try this:

```
List<Person> smallFlattened = groups.Where(x => x.Count() <= 4)
    .SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
IEnumerable<List<Person>> groupPersonLists = groups
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 4)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .Concat(new[] { smallFlattened });
```